# How to set OCR Text to canvas inside PDF document using rect(Left,Top,Right,Bottom)?

Tags: android, canvas, ocr, rect

From the Extraction of OCR I have result of Text with bounding Box the bounding box will be like "Rect(185,572-254,585)"

```
 private void createPDFDocument(int width, int height) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(width, height, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        allCollection = new ArrayList<RecognizedTextEntity>();

        for (RecognizedTextEntity  textEntity : allCollection) {
             textEntity.getRect();

             RectF rect = new RectF(textEntity.getRect());
             canvas.drawText(textEntity.getTextValue(),canvas.translate(rect,x,y,paint););
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        pdfDocument.finishPage(page);

        SavePDFtoInternalMemory(pdfDocument);
    }
}
```

The above code the canvas.drawText contain text, x-value and y value but I have four points in rect;
How to convert four point rect to two point so that it can be added to canvas.